# Конструкция языка и java.time API

Tags: java, ооп

Мое понимание реализации тела метода:

создали ссылочную переменную с именем `month` и типом `Month` , затем вызвали у объекта метод `now()` т.е присвоили действующий месяц, который, метод получается с системы. Затем в условии мы сравниваем месяц который получили методом `now()` и месяц из `enum Month`.

Вопрос 1:

Как реализуется метод `getMonth()`, и вообще конструкция `Month month = LocalDate.now().getMonth();` 
Моя догадка - когда метод `now()` получает текущую дату, то эта дата конвертируется в тип `enum`, и затем происходит присвоение, и дальнейшее выполнение оператора `if`. Верно ли мое понимание данной проблемы?

Вопрос 2:

`Month month = LocalDate.now().getMonth();` знаю что можно вызывать метод посредством `Object.method()` , но как в данном примере у нас конструкция `Object.method().method()`. Как можно вызывать одновременно два метода, и где об этом почитать.

Благодарю за помощь.

```
    static boolean isSummer() {
            Month month = LocalDate.now().getMonth();
            if (month == Month.JUNE || month == Month.JULY || month == Month.AUGUST) {
                return true;   } else {

   return false;    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос 1:

Объект `LocalDate` хранит данные в переменных:

```
/**
 * The year.
 */
private final int year;
/**
 * The month-of-year.
 */
private final short month;
/**
 * The day-of-month.
 */
private final short day;
```

И соответственно когда вызываете метод `now()` то эти переменные заполняются соответствующими значениями.

При вызове метода `getMonth()` выполняется следующий код:

```
public Month getMonth() {
    return Month.of(month);
}
```

данный код возвращает перечисление (`enum`) «конвертируя» значение из переменной типа `short` в `enum`. Все вышеперечисленное можно легко узнать, посмотрев исходные коды соответствующих классов благо в java они доступны в jdk.

> Вопрос 2:
>
> Как можно вызывать одновременно два метода, и где об этом почитать?

Смотрите у объектов есть методы которые можно вызывать через оператор `. (точка)` например `LocalDate.now()`. Эти методы могут возвращать объекты на которых так-же в свою очередь можно вызывать методы (принцип индукции). Следовательно можно писать так `LocalDate.now().getMonth()` и даже продолжить цепочку вызовов - вызвав какой нибудь из методов объекта `Month`.